# React Native Build Errors - Gradle

Tags: react-native, android-studio, build.gradle

I am having problems running my application all of a sudden.
The error are shown in the screenshot. I have no idea what has happened. What do the errors mean?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OywsF.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

App targets Android 12 or higher and contains activities, services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters. Please  explicitly declare the android: exported attribute for these app components.

Also this is applicable to all the activities, services, broadcast receivers that use an intent-filter. After making the changes. Save it , Invalidate cache and restart android studio and check